# import errors upon flask app deployment

Tags: apache, flask, web-deployment, wsgi, stormpath

I'm getting this error from apache log file after I deploy the Flask App when I try to access the website:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=20908): Exception occurred processing WSGI script'/var/www/FlaskApp/myApp.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/FlaskApp/myApp.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
        from myApp import app as application
    File "/var/www/FlaskApp/myApp/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from api import API
    File "/var/www/FlaskApp/myApp/api/API.py", line 10, in <module>
        import Query
    ImportError: No module named Query
```

My directory structure is like below:

```
FlaskApp
---myApp.wsgi
---__init__.py
---api/
------__init__.py
------API.py
------Query.py
------Email.py
```

The weird thing is that if I change `import Query` in API.py to `import Email`, it does not give any error but `Email.py` is in the same directory as `Query.py`.

When I run the app in localhost, it does not give any error, so I suspect it might be the configuration in `myApp.wsgi` file.

myApp.wsgi:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp")
from myApp import app as application
    application.secret_key = 'secret key'
```

I'm also using stormpath and I don't know if it has anything to do with this issue.

Comment: PEP 8 recommends using lowercase filenames https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names

Comment: I changed filename to using all lowercase without underscore and it still gives `No module named query`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm the author of the flask-stormpath library, but this doesn't look at all related :( Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import Query` use `from api import Query`

Comment: I tried everything with importing using `sys.path.append`, `from api import Query`, but I still get the same error. I don't get any error on `import Email`, which is in the same directory as `Query.py`.

Comment: @cloclo You have to change Email too like `from api import Query` . The `api` directory is like a package because it having `__init__.py`. So we import files from the package only. If you need to import like `import Email` and `import Query` the file should be in the same directory.In your case at FlaskApp

Comment: @cloclo Sorry i thought error in Email, Can you please specify what is the error got it now ?